# ngFor for dynamically table does not work

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im using HTML and Angular (ts)
I tried to obtain something like this dynamically because the length of data can change and i dont want to use innerHTML  :

| ListAverage1 | ListAverage2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 14 |
| 4 | 15 |
| 5 | 16 |
| 6 | 17 |
| 7 | 18 |
| 8 | 19 |

From this object:

`let average = {               "listAverage1": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], "listAverage2": [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] }`

I tried this but nothing appeared in my table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="average1">
      <th class="large8" mat-mdc-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ListAverage1 </th>
      <tr *ngFor = "let average of this.listAverage.listAverage1">
        <td>average</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="average2">
      <th class="large8" mat-mdc-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ListAverage2 </th>
      <tr *ngFor = "let average2 of this.listAverage.listAverage2">
        <td>average2</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the result of the variable.
Should be like this

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<ng-container matColumnDef="average1">
  <th class="large8" mat-mdc-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ListAverage1 </th>
   <tr *ngFor="let value of average.listAverage1">
     <td>{{ value }}</td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="average2">
  <th class="large8" mat-mdc-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ListAverage2 </th>
  <tr *ngFor="let value of average.listAverage2">
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Exactly, I miss {{}} thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="large8">listAverage1</th>
      <th class="large8">listAverage2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngIf="average.listAverage1.length === average.listAverage2.length; else lengthMismatch">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of average.listAverage1; let i = index">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ average.listAverage1[i] }}</td>
          <td>{{ average.listAverage2[i] }}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #lengthMismatch>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Arrays are of different lengths.</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

please check stackBlitz

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-sdrktx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.module.ts)